# unable to use google search api

Tags: google-api

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('JSON.php');

$url= 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?rsz=large&v=1.0&q='. $_POST['searchquery'].'&key=ABQIAAAA4oH5MwaexHdhZg4UWRNB1RT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxTzUf4N43torAasiY6JD5CaJS6n7Q&userip=http://localhost/';

echo $url;


// use fopen and fread to pull Google's search results

$handle = fopen($url, 'rb');
$body = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
$body .= fread($handle, 8192);
echo $body;
}
fclose($handle);

// now $body is the JSON encoded results. We need to decode them.

$json = new Services_JSON();
$json = $json->decode($body);

var_dump($json);
}

?>
```

When i try to run this script i get error [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

if i take the $url that is generated and paste it in address bar i get the required response.

Can anyone help and let me know how i can resolve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of your code above, try:

$url= 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?rsz=large&v=1.0&q='. $_POST['searchquery'].'&key=ABQIAAAA4oH5MwaexHdhZg4UWRNB1RT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxTzUf4N43torAasiY6JD5CaJS6n7Q&userip=http://localhost/';

$json = file_get_contents($url);

$myArr = json_decode($json);

var_dump($myArr);

i am not sure, but maybe you need to replace $_POST['searchquery'] with urlencode($_POST['searchquery']) for cases if there are spaces in the searchquery.

from: [How to retrieve & use the JSON response of website in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023560)

Comment: Thank you ...Thank you Thank you...your a genius :) it was something so simple yet i kept missing it..thanks a million